# Should the bulb tag be eliminated, or at least be made a synonym of bulbs?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [bulb](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bulb) tag had only [one question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/20671/what-is-this-bulb-with-pink-and-white-globular-flowers). I edited it out and replaced it with [bulbs](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bulbs).  At this point, should we eliminate [bulb](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bulb), or at least make it a synonym?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd be in favor of making it a synonym of [bulbs](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bulbs).

Our [tag synonyms](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) page has plenty of other examples where the singular and plural forms of a word are synonyms, so doing this would match existing practice.

Comment: The other possibility would be to just ignore it; it'll no longer be suggested as a tag when posting or editing a question after 24 hours, and it would take a moderator to recreate it since it's the singular form of an existing tag. In fact, that's what [appears to have happened here... *cough*](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/revisions/20671/2)

Comment: I did look at that list-should have asked it to be synonymized! Actually, I thought I had enough rep to suggest it until I realized I didn't meet the other criteria. Hope you have some medicine for that cough. :)